# How to create gradient button background in xamarin forms for iOS

Tags: ios, uibutton, xamarin.forms, cagradientlayer

Im creating an iPhone application in Xamarin forms which requires gradient button background. I have tried `CAGradientLayer`. But, it is not working for buttons.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?
This is my button renderer:

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged (e);

        if(e.OldElement == null)
        {

            btn = (UIButton) Control;
            btn.Frame = new RectangleF (0, 0, (float)this.Element.WidthRequest, (float)this.Element.HeightRequest);
            CAGradientLayer btnGradient = new CAGradientLayer ();
            btnGradient.Frame = btn.Bounds;
            btnGradient.Colors = new CGColor[]{ Color.White.ToCGColor(), Color.FromHex("#0073BD").ToCGColor() };
            btn.Layer.InsertSublayer (btnGradient, 0);
            btn.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
            btn.Layer.BorderColor = Color.FromHex("#0073BE").ToCGColor();
            btn.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
            btn.SetTitleColor(Color.Black.ToUIColor (), UIControlState.Normal);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your custom renderer ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest just making the gradient images up front and using those directly unless you need to have dynamically created gradients at runtime. If you go the image route then you'll do something like:

```
var regImg = UIImage.FromBundle("myimage.png").ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal);
var selImg = UIImage.FromBundle("myimage_selected.png").ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal);

Control.SetBackgroundImage(regImg, UIControlState.Normal);
Control.SetBackgroundImage(selImg, UIControlState.Highlighted);
```

If you still want to go the dynamically created gradient route, take a look at this post - you'll see he is dynamically creating his images via a ImageWithColor() method he's created:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/32240/set-buttontype-in-buttonrenderer-ios-specific

Finally, be sure you are setting the ImageType of the button to Custom - I don't see you setting that in your renderer, and by default iOS draws borderless buttons after iOS7 I believe.